# Binding to Static class property and StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, data-binding

I am able to bind a static class property to a MenuItem header, but I cannot determine how to include a StringFormat so that I can display hard-coded text in addition to the property.

Is this possible?

Currently: (Displays "SQLSERVER1")

```
Header="{x:Static settings:Settings.CurrentServer}"
```

Desired: (Display "Connection: SQLSERVER1")

```
Header="{Binding Source={x:Static Settings:Settings.CurrentServer},StringFormat='Connection: {0}'}"
```

When I try the 'Desired' line in the XAML the StringFormat is ignored entirely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there should not be any quote, try removing the `'` quotes around the value of StringFormat.

Comment: @Hopeless No change.

Comment: consider escaping the `{0}` such as `\{0\}` or `{}{0}`

Comment: @Hopeless still no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MenuItem` provides a `HeaderStringFormat` property that you should use:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={x:Static Settings:Settings.CurrentServer}}"
          HeaderStringFormat="Connection: {0}" />
```

Actually, that property is part of `HeaderedItemsControl`, which `MenuItem` happens to extend.

The `StringFormat` property is just ignored.

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me as of .NET 5:

```
<Window Title="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:ApplicationSettings.ProductName}, StringFormat='{}{0} Document'}" />
```

where `ProductName` is defined as:

```
public static string ProductName {get { ... ; } }
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I suffered a similar problem and got around it by utilising `ContentControl` and it's separate `ContentStringFormat` property:

```
<TextBlock Cursor="Help" Text="Hello World" >
    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Source={x:Static local:SomeStaticClass}}" ContentStringFormat="Hello {0}" />
    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score -1):

StringFormat is disregarded for Content and Header, because their TargetType is not System.String.  Those properties have corresponding *StringFormat properties to get around that limitation.